# What should be done to run tests in order in which they are defined?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I've following code:

```
require 'test/unit'

class Flow < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_hi
        puts "Hi"
    end

    def test_working
        puts "Working"
    end

    def test_bye
        puts "Bye"
    end

    def test_tired
        puts "Tired"
    end
end
```

When I run it, it displays following:

```
Bye
Hi
Tired
Working
```

Looking at output, I can guess that the tests are executed in alphabetical order of the test names(i.e. alphabetical order of text field in test_text).

Actually, I want to execute my test in the order which I defined. Means for above script, I want following output:

```
Hi
Working
Bye
Tired
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Order-dependent tests is evil. No, it's EVIL. It will backfire and it will be very painful. You've been warned.

Comment: Could you please suggest another Ruby test framework by which we can achieve this?

Comment: You need not to achieve it, that was my point. If you need this, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks everybody!!! BTW, who edited my question with an another stackoverflow question? It also helped. Thanks whoever it is!

Answer (score 4):

Although I agree with Sergio that this should not be done, I found this by looking at the source of Test::Unit::TestCase

(https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/master/lib/test/unit/testcase.rb):

```
    # Sets the current test order.
    #
    # Here are the available _order_:
    # [:alphabetic]
    #   Default. Tests are sorted in alphabetic order.
    # [:random]
    #   Tests are sorted in random order.
    # [:defined]
    #   Tests are sorted in defined order.
    def test_order=(order)
      @@test_orders[self] = order
    end
```

So, if you set the test_order of the TestCase to :defined, it should be working.

Comment: I tried with test_order = :defined but it's not working as expected and when I tried self.test_order = :defined it throws error: test.rb:4:in `<class:Flow>': undefined method `test_order=' for Flow:Class (NoMethodError)
        from test.rb:3:in `<main>'

Comment: Thanks mario for pointing to doc. It's helping to understand Test:Unit

Comment: No problem, this was just the natural choice to look for references. Although I am still puzzled why this does not work as advertised.